# how to select last response from multiple answers with NA from multiple columns in wide format data in R

Tags: r

df

```
 ID         V1             V2              V3           V4           V5         V6                          
 1 10007       PrEP EXP       NA              PrEP FU      NA           NA         NA          
 2 10038       NA             NA              PrEP FU      NA           NA         PrEP EXP             
 3 10039       PrEP FU        NA              NA           NA           PrepFU EXP PrEP EN             
 4 10058       NA             NA              PrepFU EXP   PrEP FU      NA         NA             
 5 10062       NA             NA              PrepFU EXP   NA           NA         PrEP FU
```

How to select only last response to create new variable from above dataset.
output variable would be

```
    ID         V1             V2              V3           V4           V5         V6          Output                
 1 10007       PrEP EXP       NA              PrEP FU      NA           NA         NA          PrepFU 
 2 10038       NA             NA              PrEP FU      NA           NA         PrEP EXP    PrEP EXP         
 3 10039       PrEP FU        NA              NA           NA           PrepFU EXP PrEP EN     PrEP EN         
 4 10058       NA             NA              PrepFU EXP   PrEP FU      NA         NA          PrEP FU    
 5 10062       NA             NA              PrepFU EXP   NA           NA         PrEP FU     PrEP FU
```

Any code in r or suggestions would be appreciated.     r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use  `max.col` to get the column index of the last non-NA element for each row, `cbind` with sequence of rows to extract the element that correspond to the `i`, `j` index

```
df1$Output <- df1[-1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), max.col(!is.na(df1[-1]), 'last'))]
```

Comment: This is awesome, Thanks @akrun